# Xna Collision Dection

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

Hi guys im making a simple tron lightcycle type game in xna and wondered if anyone knew what the most efficient way of drawing the trail and doing collision on it would be?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will get any useful answers with a question like this. It's very ambiguous. You need to be more specific. Also - rendering and collision detection are two different questions, so you should be asking them separately IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on whether it's a 3d or 2d game, but I think these tutorials should cover the way of doing effects for both:

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/3d-tutorials

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-tutorials

For 3d collision detection, you can use [BoundingBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox.aspx) objects to approximate a light cycle, and possibly a [BoundingSphere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingsphere.aspx) could also come in handy.4

EDIT:

Where `LightEmitter` is a Vector2 where the trail will come out,

`LightTrail` is a Texture2D with a 1-pixel wide section of light trail,

`LastEmitterPos` is a Vector2 showing the last position of `LightEmitter`

and Trails is a RenderTarget2D whose `RenderTargetUsage` is set to `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents`:

example Draw method:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Trails);

spriteBatch.Begin();


for (float i = 0; i <= (LightEmitter - LastEmitterPos).Length(); i++)
{
    Vector2 Pos = Vector2.Lerp(LastEmitterPos, LightEmitter, i/(LightEmitter - LastEmitterPos).Length());
    spriteBatch.Draw(LightTrail, Pos, new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 3), Color.White, MathHelper.ToRadians(90.0f), new Vector2(16, 1.5f), 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
}

spriteBatch.End();

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(Trails, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
```

There are a few glitches and a lot of optimization needed here but I'm sure this can give you a good idea what direction to go in. Or at least a bit of encouragement if nothing else ;)

Comment: You can tile a texture of the trail for the effect and use Rectangles to do collision detection with Rectangle.Intersects(), here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx

Comment: I tried using rectangles but wont it slow down the game when you're getting hundreds of them for each player, i.e whenever they change direction?

Comment: If your lightcycles only go in four directions you only need one rectangle, otherwise you need angle-aligned bounding boxes, which aren't in xna but can be implemented with external libraries

Comment: Yeah i've got a bounding box on the cycle its just the trail im having trouble with

Comment: You can tile a thin part of the light cycle trail image again and again everywhere the lightcycles go. If you can't figure it out yourself, I can give you a more thorough example.

Comment: I've hadn a go but can't seen to get it right, an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've added an example, it needs some work and for collision detection you can use a per-pixel detection, or if you can find something better use that. You'll also need to implement rotation.

Answer (score 2):

For a 2D game, Rectangles are a quick/easy way to get a basic collision detection.

MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx)

Since you only have to set the Rectangle boundaries for each object you want to detect collisions and then test the `Rectangle1.Intersects(Rectangle2)` Condition to see if they touch.

Comment: Since rectangles don't go round corners how would they be linked up?

Comment: For the round corners part I found an article where they seem to solve this problem.
[here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13268/rounded-corners-in-xna).
And no I don't think Using lots of rectangles will slow your game down see it as an other sprite invisibly drawn over the existing sprites and following the moving sprites around.